# Wrong response schema in OpenApi UI using SpringDoc with swagger yaml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm having a issue where the response schema for the erros codes, such 400, 500 e etc. not being show as a no content in the swagger UI. It replicate the schema set for the 200 response code, when using the yaml file generated code.

I'm using the springdoc dependency to configure the UI from the swagger, in the documentation of springdoc I found that you can define no content response schema using this annotattions:
[springdoc-documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auv5W.png)

The main problem is that the code is generated by the swagger codegen, which I cannot modify and applied the solution present in the documentation. Here's my code:

**The yaml file:**

```
400:
  description: Requisição inválida
  content: { }
401:
  description: Falha na autenticação
  content: { }
500:
  description: Erro no sistema
  content: { }
```

**The generated code:**

```
@ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "202", description = "Solicitação recebida com sucesso.", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ObjectName.class))),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Requisição inválida"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "401", description = "Falha na autenticação"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Erro no sistema") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/evento-nao-financeiro",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        consumes = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default ResponseEntity<StatusSafRepresentation> methodName
```

As you can see, I need to add the code 'content = @Content(schema = @Schema(hidden = true))' in those apiResponses that isn't the 202 status.

Ps: I'm using the latest dependency from springdoc

`<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId> <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId> <version>1.7.0</version>`